# Elixir: Sort struct fields in inspect output

Tags: elixir

I'm debugging a struct that has more than 80 fields. I'm trying to find a way to sort output of `inspect` function for this struct. Currently it's random and it's make impossible to diff the output in any meaningful way. I've tried to implement `Inspect` protocol but I've kept running into issue that some values were not convertable to string. When I've swapped `"#{item.field}"` string format for `"#{inspect(item.field)}"` I got error saying `Kernel.inspect/2 conflicts with local function`. Here's code sample:

```
defimpl Inspect, for: App.Record do
  def inspect(record, opts) do
    """
    {Record}
    --------------------------------------------------------
    matched_clear_transaction : #{inspect(record.data, opts)}
    --------------------------------------------------------
    """
end
```

`inspect(record.data)` produces hard to read data unformatted on foreign keys.

Comment: Have you checked `IO.inspect`?

Comment: Like @Alan says try to change: `matched_clear_transaction : #{IO.inspect(record.data, opts)}`